# Python ctypes Windows operations - script fails in 64bit interpreter, but works fine in 32bit interpreter

Tags: python, windows, api, ctypes, 32bit-64bit

The following piece of code uses only standard libraries, and runs without an error in a 32bit Python 3.6 interpreter, but returns an error in a 64bit one (Windows handle is invalid):

```
import ctypes, ctypes.wintypes

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000010
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122
ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
MAXIMUM_USB_STRING_LENGTH = 255

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

setupapi = ctypes.windll.setupapi
SetupDiGetClassDevs = setupapi.SetupDiGetClassDevsW
SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces = setupapi.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces
SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail = setupapi.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW

CM_Get_Parent = setupapi.CM_Get_Parent
CM_Get_Device_ID = setupapi.CM_Get_Device_IDW
CM_Request_Device_Eject = setupapi.CM_Request_Device_EjectW

class GUID(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Data1", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("Data2", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("Data3", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("Data4", ctypes.c_ubyte * 8)]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{%08X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%012X}' % (
            self.Data1, self.Data2, self.Data3,
            self.Data4[0] * 256 + self.Data4[1],
            self.Data4[2] * (256 ** 5) +
            self.Data4[3] * (256 ** 4) +
            self.Data4[4] * (256 ** 3) +
            self.Data4[5] * (256 ** 2) +
            self.Data4[6] * 256 +
            self.Data4[7])

class SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
            ("ClassGuid", GUID),
            ("DevInst", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
            ("Reserved", ctypes.c_void_p)
            ]

class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
            ("InterfaceClassGuid", GUID),
            ("Flags", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
            ("Reserved", ctypes.c_void_p)
            ]

class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
            ("DevicePath", ctypes.c_wchar*255)]

GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME = GUID(0x53F5630D, 0xB6BF, 0x11D0,
        (ctypes.c_ubyte*8)(0x94, 0xF2, 0x00, 0xA0, 0xC9, 0x1E, 0xFB, 0x8B))

hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ctypes.byref(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME),
                               0,
                               0,
                               DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE)
if hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
    print(ctypes.windll.GetLastError(), ctypes.windll.FormatError())


def get_device_interface(i, device=None):
    interfaceData = SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA()
    interfaceData.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA)
    if SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
        hDevInfo,
        device and ctypes.byref(device) or None,
        ctypes.byref(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME),
        i,
        ctypes.byref(interfaceData)):
        return interfaceData
    elif ctypes.GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS:
        return
    else:
        print(ctypes.GetLastError(), ctypes.FormatError())

def connected_devices():
    interface_index = 0
    interface = get_device_interface(interface_index)

devices  = connected_devices()
```

I suspect that the issue is not strictly a Python problem, but rather a difference in how 64 and 32 bit interpreter types interact with Windows.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You're missing the function prototypes, which is going to be problematic with 64-bit pointers since the default conversion is a 32-bit C `int`. You're naively assuming a 32-bit int conversion for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead using `wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value`. You're unreliably using `ctypes.windll` and `GetLastError()` via FFI instead of `ctype.WinDLL` with `use_last_error=True` and `ctypes.get_last_error()`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for your comments. I now understand why INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE must be platform derived, thank you. But I don't understand your other comments about the difference between WinDLL and windll. I have made changes to the code (those that I assumed you meant) and I still get the same behaviour.

Comment: Define the function prototypes, e.g. `SetupDiGetClassDevsW.restype` (a single ctypes type) and `SetupDiGetClassDevsW.argtypes` (a sequence of ctypes types). Otherwise the default integer conversion is from/to a 32-bit integer, which will truncate 64-bit pointer values.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you, I have added function prototypes, using PySerial library as an example. Now the python interpreter just fails due to maximum recursion depth: https://github.com/tonysepia/tests/blob/master/test.py Have I done it the wrong way?

Comment: Don't use `_pack_`; the structures have native alignment. Use wide-character `wintypes.PCWSTR` instead of `PCTSTR = ctypes.c_char_p`. Use the `WinDLL` option `use_last_error=True`, and check the last error via `ctypes.get_last_error()` instead of `GetLastError`; it captures the last error value immediately after the call, which is the safest approach in a high-level scripting environment in which you can't be completely certain what gets called between bytecode operations in the interpreter.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces.argtypes` should be `POINTER(GUID)` instead of `GUID`. `SetupDiGetClassDevsW.errcheck` should raise `ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())` if the call fails with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, else return `arguments`; don't return anything else unless you're changing the return value. `errcheck` for the other two functions should check the boolean result. don't rely on `WinError()` without an explicit error code; otherwise it just calls `GetLastError`, which isn't reliable.

Comment: Since you're defining `errcheck` functions, which raise an exception for an error, the code that calls the ctypes functions should be rewritten to use idiomatic exception handling, i.e. use try-except-finally and handle `OSError` by examining the error code in the `winerror` attribute of the exception.

Comment: Thank you, @eryksun, I think that I have significantly advanced and improved my understanding of what the code does through your help. However, I've hit a stumbling block at the point where I am calling SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail within get_device_interface_detail function - it clearly returns False, but the ctypes.get_last_error() simply prints '0'. Why does the function return False? How do I get the last error? Your ongoing help is greatly appreciated! I have updated the code here: https://github.com/tonysepia/tests/blob/master/test.py

Comment: It should be `setupapi = ctypes.WinDLL('setupapi', use_last_error=True)`. There are still other problems in your script that I think are all addressed by my previous comments. If we can get past the hurdle of ctypes technicalities, then there may be a more interesting problem here related to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you so much for your ongoing help. I have again modified the repository github.com/tonysepia/tests/blob/master/test.py with latest changes, but now I am getting the ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER - 1784 (0x6F8) - The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation error, as an error code returned by SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW. I have tried setting the last to parameters to NULL as they are optional ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetailw ) but it makes no difference.Could you please have a look?

Comment: For convenience and correctness, your structures should have `__init__` methods that set `cbSize` to the fixed size, `ctypes.sizeof(self)`. In `get_device_interface_detail`, the value of `detail` should be set initially to `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_W()`. The first call will fail due to insufficient buffer. Then you must resize the buffer via `size = length.value;` `ctypes.resize(detail, size)`.

Comment: When it succeeds, you can't simply return the single character `detail.DevicePath`. You have to create the array type, `arr_t = c_wchar * length` where `length = (size - offset) // ctypes.sizeof(c_wchar)` and `offset = type(detail).DevicePath.offset`. And then convert to a Python string via `dev_path = arr_t.from_address(ctypes.addressof(detail) + offset).value`.

Comment: @eryksun. Amazing! I thought that I could change the seize of the struct by incrementing cbSize parameter, but it hasn't made a difference - I was still getting the 1784 error code. However, when I tried your suggestion to use ctypes.resize it has miraculously worked, even without changing the internal cbSize property! Docs say that 'resize' resizes the memory buffer, but I can't see that reflected in my PyCharm object explorer.. interesting

Comment: @eryksun Thanks to all your help, I've learned a lot about ctypes and the code now works fine in a 64bit Python interpreter. However, it now fails in the 32-bit one! https://github.com/tonysepia/tests/blob/master/test.py  I think you have solved the problem for me, but I am not sure what to publish as an answer, as a take-away for the Stack Overflow community. What do you think?

Comment: I'll consolidate these comments into a meaningful answer and make another pass over your code to add some finishing touches and try to resolve whatever is misbehaving in a 32-bit process.

Comment: This is a great answer @ErykSun but you might want to basically copypasta your comments here as an answer for votes.